# c++ propper overriding of new[] and delete[]

Tags: c++, memory, overloading

In [this](http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html) library there are the following global overrides for `new`, `delete`, `new[]` and `delete[]`:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* ---------------------- new and delete ---------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ---------------------------------------- operator new */

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *p = MemTrack::TrackMalloc(size);
    if (p == NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();
    return p;
}

/* ---------------------------------------- operator delete */

void operator delete(void *p)
{
    MemTrack::TrackFree(p);
}

/* ---------------------------------------- operator new[] */

void *operator new[](size_t size)
{
    void *p = MemTrack::TrackMalloc(size);
    if (p == NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();
    return p;
}

/* ---------------------------------------- operator delete[] */

void operator delete[](void *p)
{
    MemTrack::TrackFree(p);
}
```

The overrides for `new` and `delete` make sense to me. But what about `new[]` and `delete[]`? AFAIK in c++ when a new array is created using `new[]`, it also stores the number of elements before the pointer, so that `delete[]` can call the destructors on the elements. Does this need to be considered when overriding `new[]` and `delete[]` or is there some kind of implicit "wrapper" that adds that on the outside of whatever the overriding implementation allocates?
If not, how is it done properly? it seems the `new[]` operator also only gets the number of bytes that should be allocated, and not the number of elements.

Comment: The new/delete operators are responsible for the memory de/allocation. The constructor/destructor calls and array loops are handled separately. See the comments and code under Global replacements [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong

> AFAIK in c++ when a new array is created using new[], it also stores
> the number of elements

Nothing in C++ says how `new[]` must be implemented.

Note `new` and `new[]` are not the same as `operator new` and `operator new[]`, The former call constructors (and maybe in the case of `new[]` do some bookkeeping to track how many elements are constructed, I guess this is the wrapper you mentioned). The only responsibility of `operator new` and `operator new[]` is to allocate sufficient memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), the standard library implementation of `new[]` actually calls `new`:

> 2. Called by the array form of new[]-expressions to allocate all
>    storage required for an array (including possible new-expression
>    overhead). The standard library implementation calls version (1)

Makes sense, because in both cases the parameter `size` of the `operator new` indicates the number of bytes to be allocated, neglecting the number of objects, which is irrelevant to this operator. The operator that cares about the number of objects is `operator []`.